# How to pass std::less to a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, comparator

I want to pass a `std::less` but pass it as a template to a class, like this:

```
template<typename Comparator>
class MyClass{
    static Comparator comp;//Looks like this class in not multithread-safe :p
public:
    int value;
    bool operator<(const MyClass& other){return comp(this->value, other.value);}
};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    MyClass<std::less<int> > mc1{3};
    MyClass<std::less<int> > mc2{5};

    cout << (mc1 < mc2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But in the initialization of `mc1` and `mc2` I get the error:

> undefined reference to `MyClass<std::less<int> >::comp'

How can I make this work? (without any change of the tactic of passing `std::less` as an argument to the class, etc)?

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/X3046B), which compiler are you using? The fact that you are using `> >` instead of `>>` in your template instantiations makes me think you are using a pre-C++11 compiler. So, like any other `static` variable, you will likely need to add a storage definition for `comp` outside of the class declaration, eg: `std::less<int> MyClass<std::less<int> >::comp;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau the `static` variable is only declared, not defined. This should not compile.

Comment: @Fureeish I'm aware of that, but it [does compile](https://ideone.com/X3046B) for me without a separate definition for `comp`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It compiles, but it [doesn't link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iseY4O1xICNCwB0b).

Comment: @RemyLebeau [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/nc4boj) you can reproduce.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this site uses GCC 8.3. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fEKj7v) produces assembly for this code, but ultimately fails when linking with *undefined reference*.

Comment: Note that you may not need `comp`: https://godbolt.org/z/nPdbnP

Comment: @RemyLebeau im using MinGW Distro (GCC 9.2.0) and yes, looks like i try to separate them to see it was that. But it does work by declaring the static variable

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that this code shouldn't link.  And yet, somehow ideone is able to run the code just fine. So I wonder how it gets past the linker issue?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Missing definition is ill-formed no diagnostic required. With optimisations, the method is inlined to not require `comp` thus no linker error

Comment: @Artyer Is a `static` even allowed to be optimized away?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, no: https://godbolt.org/z/We4nov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other `static` class variable, you would need to provide a storage definition for `comp` for every specific template instantiation that you want to use, eg:

```cpp
template<typename Comparator>
class MyClass{
    static Comparator comp;//Looks like this class in not multithread-safe :p
public:
    int value;
    bool operator<(const MyClass& other){return comp(this->value, other.value);}
};

template<>
std::less<int> MyClass<std::less<int> >::comp; // <-- add this

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    MyClass<std::less<int> > mc1{3};
    MyClass<std::less<int> > mc2{5};

    cout << (mc1 < mc2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, [even this](https://godbolt.org/z/EKGseo) didn't resolve the "unresolved" linker error.

In modern C++, you can initialize `comp` inline instead:

```cpp
template<typename Comparator>
class MyClass {
    static constexpr auto comp = Comparator{};
public:
    int value;
    bool operator<(const MyClass& other) {
        return comp(this->value, other.value);
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/We4nov)

Otherwise, you can move the declaration of `comp` inside of your `operator<` instead:

```cpp
template<typename Comparator>
class MyClass{
public:
    int value;
    bool operator<(const MyClass& other){
        static Comparator comp;
        return comp(this->value, other.value);
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ex7hE8)

Or, just get rid of `comp` altogether:

```cpp
template<typename Comparator>
class MyClass{
public:
    int value;
    bool operator<(const MyClass& other){
        return Comparator()(this->value, other.value);
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nPdbnP)